# network status - wrong version - I think the GUI wallet needs updating

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

i think my monero wallet is out of date as i have not opened it in a few months.
It's v01410_boron_butterfly, is there a latest version I can update & not lose my coins in the process?
A link to show me where to find the latest version on 64bit windows 10 would be great? (then i would not need to ask for a link to the latest version every few months)

Comment: The v0.15 release thread (which contains upgrading instructions) can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/e0j98n/gui_v01501_carbon_chamaeleon_released/

Comment: Even if something wonky happens when you upgrade, you won't lose your coins. Just make sure you have your seed written down so you can recover the coins if you damage the wallet file.  You may want to save the wallet file as a backup as well, though it's very unlikely you'll need it.

Comment: thank you both for your help. Any thoughts on Coinomi wallet? Once I access my XMR I'm tempted to move it there to save upgrading my GUI wallet every few months when i log onto to it.